# Getting error when turning key logger off due to atexit() function

Tags: c, function, logging, atexit

I get a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` when turning off my key logger when there is an `atexit()` function in my code. This is confusing because the `atexit()` function should only be called when somebody attempts to exit the program (not simply when a command is given to turn off the key logger).

If I take out the line `atexit(final)` in my main, everything works properly. But I need `atexit()` function in my code to take care of what happens when the person exits the shell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code won't even compile. The main() function is incomplete, and there are several variable declarations missing.

Comment: Sorry I removed variable declarations and irrelevant code. My actual main has a return O and everything :)

Comment: If this accurately reflects your real code you are registering the `atexit` (and `signal`) every time through the input loop.  If that's the case final is going to be called multiple times and probably won't react well to trying to read deleted files.

Comment: How can I fix this, Duck?

Comment: Please provide a test program which is as small as possible and which demonstrates your problem.